# probability of left maximum

Tags: probability-theory

I came across this question while searching for a different question on internet. 
Given a random permutation π of [n] = {1, 2, . . . , n}, we say that
i is a left maximum if πi > πj for all j < i. What is the expected number of
left maxima in a random permutation.

Could someone please help me with this question?

Thanks,
El

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be a random variable which is 1 if $i$ is a left maximum and 0 if not.  Then the number of left maxima is

$$M := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$$

and by linearity of expectation we have

$$E[M] = E[X_1] + \cdots + E[X_n]$$

Of course $E[X_i]$ is just the probability that $i$ is a left maximum.  And that can be worked out just by counting #(favorable permutations) / #(all permutations).